# Using Multiple filters in DAX

Tags: excel, pivot, dax, powerbi

I'm new to DAX.

I'm currently using Power BI and trying to create a total sum of sales that use a few different SKUs (or IDs)

I can use this to filter down to 1 sku ("A1"):

Measure = CALCULATE([Sum of Sales],Table4[SKU]="A1")

but I would like to filter down to five different SKUs.

Example Data:

```
2      1,050.54
3     43,925.20
4      8,596.00
5      1,630.00
8      3,330.00
A1        45.24
A2       499.87
A3    53,567.05
A4       337.92
A5     4,265.00
AB    12,651.94
ACC    7,634.95
ADV   -1,769.95
ANT        1.60
AUTO   9,655.40
BOOT     268.00
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you edit your question to format your  example data into a table. This way we can get a better idea of how your data looks. Also, is Sum of Sales a calculated column that you have added to your powerpivot model?

Comment: Typically you would create your Measure to filter on SKU, then use the User Interface to filter for the SKUs you want (via slicer or filter)

Answer (score 12):

[CALCULATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634825.aspx) is defined as `CALCULATE(<expression>,<filter1>,<filter2>…)` This means that you can use multiple filters at one time. However, the multiple filters will act **at the same time**. Meaning that the data would have to meet both conditions.

So doing `BadSumOfSales:=CALCULATE([Sum of Sales],Table3[SKU]="A1",Table4[SKU]="AB")` will not give you what you need. Since the SKU would have to be equal to A1 **and** AB, it will return *blank*

Since you have five items you would like to included in your filtering, you should leverage the [SWITCH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492166.aspx) function. This will allow you to accommodate multiple conditions that should return [TRUE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee635034.aspx) and then let you return [FALSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634894.aspx) for anything else

```
TotalsSumOfSales:=CALCULATE([Sum Of Sales],
SWITCH(Table4[SKU],
    "A1",TRUE(),
    "A2",TRUE(),
    "A3",TRUE(),
    "4" ,TRUE(),
    "5" ,TRUE(),
    "8" ,TRUE(),
      FALSE()  
))
```

Another way to get around this would be using the [OR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634951.aspx) function. This is a great option, but only really works well when you have two filters at a time. If you have more than two, you will have to do some nesting that can get complex. So for your case I would stick with the [SWITCH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492166.aspx), but here is an example of how it would look:

```
OrTotalSumOfSales:=CALCULATE([Sum of Sales],
OR(
    Table4[SKU]="A1",
    Table4[SKU]="A2"
))
```

Answer (score 7):

The best idea in this case is to use `IN` Operator in DAX. The Performance is way better than pipe operator or `OR` and the code becomes more readable.

This is only supported in the latest versions of DAX.

```
GroupingSales:=CALCULATE([Sum of Sales],Table[SKU] IN {"A1","A2","A3","AB"})
```

You can also use `CONTAINSROW`.

More info: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/the-in-operator-in-dax/

Answer (score 3):

Just a third way alternative to the Or version.
 You can use the double pipes '||' which acts as an Or statement in the filter.

```
Measure = CALCULATE([Sum of Sales],Table4[SKU]="A1" || Table4[SKU]="A2" || 
Table4[SKU]="A3" ||Table4[SKU]="A4" || Table4[SKU]="A5")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I think based on your request to filter down to 5 different SKUs that you actually shouldn't be using DAX to solve your problem.

If you just insert a pivot table in Excel you can add SKU to rows and sales to values.  If you need, you can adjust the aggregate (but I think it defaults to SUM) so you should already have the right data.  Only thing remaining is to filter it down to just the SKUs you want.  You can do the same in Power View just by creating a table.  Then you can add SKU to the filter pane and select the 5 skus you want.

Appreciate your using Power BI,
-Lukasz

- http://dev.powerbi.com
- http://blogs.msdn.com/powerbidev
- Make a feature request: https://support.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi
- Sign up for Power BI: http://www.powerbi.com